# Why does Lib.current.stage give me an error?

Tags: listener, haxe, stage, openfl

Why `Lib.current.stage` gives me this error:

> src/Main.hx:43: characters 2-35 : openfl.display.DisplayObject cannot be called

**Edit:** I have tried the following code.

```
Lib.current.stage.addEventLitener(
    KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,
    function(e:KeyboardEvent) {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.W) up = true;
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.A) left = true;
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.D) right = true;
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.S) down = true;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MovieClip implements `Dynamic<MovieClip>` so that any reference not in the class definition is assumed to be a MovieClip.

You've got a typo there on addEventLitener, missing an 's' which isn't in the class definition, so is assumed to be a MovieClip, which cannot be called.